# Вылетает nouveau на live USB Ubuntu

Tags: установка

На ноутбук MSI с 1050 запускаю с флешки убунту ( пробовал хубунту и мате ещё ), рабочий стол запускается, вылетает секунд через 10, чёрный экран выдает нуви ( скрин https://m.imgur.com/a/OQ3UmwI , став не хочет грузить больше 2 мб ), через несколько секунд вылетает сообщение типа вытащите флешку и нажмите enter для перезагрузки. Как мне поставить убунту?

Answer (score 0):

Часто при установке операционных систем используют одну и ту же флешку. Если вы использовали эту флешку для установки Windows или других версий Linux, то скорее всего вы ее просто неправильно почистили или выбрали несовместимый формат записи самой флешки.
Попробуйте сменить программу для монтирования iso образов и смените флешку. Если все сделаете грамотно, а проблема останется - возможно проблема в вашей видеокарте.

Чёрный экран в Ubuntu при загрузке, может быть вызван разными причинами, например:

1. Обновлением системы;
2. Повреждением файловой системы из за неожиданного отключения от сети;
3. Несовместимостью драйверов видеокарты;
4. Отсутствием необходимых для инициализации программ.

В случае, если проблема в железе - вариантов решения просто уйма и выбрать какой-то один конкретный с таким количеством информации затруднительно.
Я предполагаю, что все-таки проблема именно во флешке и методе записи на неё iso образа, ибо это самая распространённая проблема. 
Скриншот, кстати, ваш не открывается.